# Using Laravel to create LMS and assign courses to students

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to create a simple LMS system using Laravel. I'm following a youtube guide and the QuickLMS repo here: https://github.com/LaravelDaily/QuickLMS/. Most of the app is working just fine, however there is one function I want to change and get rid of.

I struggle with a specific function which is assigning a student or user to a course. Whenever a student opens a course on the front page, a button is displayed at the top which says "Buy course", this loads the Stripe popup for the student to pay. when payment is done, course is assigned to student in course_student table.

The code I'm borrowing from uses Stripe to take payment for a course. I want this button to be a "enroll in course" button, rather than a payment button. So that when the student enters the course, a button to enroll in course is displayed instead, which add the students to the course_student table without the need of any payment info.

*CoursesController.php:*

```
public function payment(Request $request)
    {
        $course = Course::findOrFail($request->get('course_id'));
        $this->createStripeCharge($request);
        $course->students()->attach(\Auth::id());
        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Payment completed successfully.');
    }
    private function createStripeCharge($request)
    {
        Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_API_KEY'));
        try {
            $customer = Customer::create([
                'email' => $request->get('stripeEmail'),
                'source'  => $request->get('stripeToken')
            ]);
            $charge = Charge::create([
                'customer' => $customer->id,
                'amount' => $request->get('amount'),
                'currency' => "usd"
            ]);
        } catch (\Stripe\Error\Base $e) {
            return redirect()->back()->withError($e->getMessage())->send();
        }
    }
```

*course.blade.php:*

```
<form action="{{ route('courses.payment') }}" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" name="course_id" value="{{ $course->id }}" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="{{ $course->price * 100 }}" />
                    <script
                            src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                            data-key="{{ env('PUB_STRIPE_API_KEY') }}"
                            data-amount="{{ $course->price * 100 }}"
                            data-currency="usd"
                            data-name="Quick LMS"
                            data-label="Buy course (${{ $course->price }})"
                            data-description="Course: {{ $course->title }}"
                            data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
                            data-locale="auto"
                            data-zip-code="false">
                    </script>
```

*web.php:*

```
Route::post('course/payment', ['uses' => 'CoursesController@payment', 'as' => 'courses.payment']);
```

I tried changing all this by removing any references to Stripe, and instead creating a new function that looks like this:

CoursesController.php:

```
 public function register (Request $request)
    {
        $this->createSubscription($request);
        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Payment completed successfully.');

    }

    private function createSubscription($request)
    {
        $course = Course::findOrFail($request->get('course_id'));
        $course->students()->attach(\Auth::id());
    }
```

However, this only generates a "page expired" message from Laravel, and I can't figure out how to just drop the Stripe button.

I have tried to replace the whole "payment" function without success. I think this is the code I want, but it obviously needs some change to work, I can't figure it out though:

```
        $course->students()->attach(\Auth::id());
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this myself by creating two new functions:
**CoursesController.php:**

```
public function register (Request $request)
    {
        $course = Course::findOrFail($request->get('course_id'));
        $this->createSubscription($request);
        $course->students()->attach(\Auth::id());
        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Payment completed successfully.');


    }

    private function createSubscription($request)
    {
        return;

    }
```

**And the following form on course.blade.php:**

```
 <form action="{{ route('courses.register') }}" method="POST">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <input type="hidden" name="course_id" value="{{ $course->id }}" />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit me"></form>
```

**Web.php**

```
Route::post('course/register/', ['uses' => 'CoursesController@register', 'as' => 'courses.register']);
```

It could maybe be done in a better way, but this does what I was looking for.